# Why doesn't parse reset the PFuser on logout?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, authentication

I am using:

```
} else if segue.identifier == "logout" {

    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    PFUser.logOut()
}
```

After I click the logout button, it segues to the login screen again, however if I click on the login button it logs that user back in without having to put in any credentials again.

Why didn't it reset the user to nil upon logout?

```
@IBAction func logIn(sender: AnyObject) {

    if username.text == "" || password.text == "" {

       displayNewAlert("Field(s) Empty", message: "Please Enter a Username and Password")

    } else {

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()


        let user = PFUser()
        user.username = username.text
        user.password = password.text

        var errorMessage = "Please Try Again Later"

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text!, password: password.text!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            if user != nil {

               self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)

            } else {

                if let errorString = error!.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                    errorMessage = errorString

                }

                self.displayNewAlert("Failed Log In", message: "Please enter a valid username and password")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that executes when they press the login button?

Comment: @Paulw11 i added the code for it. check it out

Comment: So are your username and password text fields empty?  Why do you create a PFUser outside the closure and then check it for non-nil inside the closure?  That is wrong. In the closure you should first check error for non-nil. If error is nil then check that PFUser.currentUser is non-nil. You don't need the `user` variable at all

Comment: The reason why 'currentUser' isn't set to null after you logOut, is becaue 'PFUser.logOut()' is called after you set the value of the variable 'currentUser'. Try to call 'PFUser.logOut()' before declaring the variable.

Comment: @Dridia that didn't work, tried it.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, they are empty. i click login, and it logs in the most recent user. As far as your explanation, it is alittle hard for me to understand as i am quite new to this. Would you mind writing that in code?

Comment: I am on my phone so I can't really write code but where you have `if user!=nil` you should have `if error == nil`

Comment: @MatthewEhrlich If you in the same view as the login button, execute the following commands `print("value of CurrentUser: ", PFUser.currentUser)`. What information are you provided in the log?

Comment: @Dridia it shows me the value of the most recently logged in user. Now i can enter the app without adding credentials. Just by tapping login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Figured out the issue, for anyone else wondering. I was doing a storyboard segue between logout and login.

i should have been using:

```
@IBAction func logOut(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logOut()
let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is the correct way to perform a logout. Not from the above mentioned

```
    segue.identifier == "....."
```